# How can I place a button inside a Google Maps InfoWindow using Nativescript and Dapriett's nativescript-google-maps-sdk plugin

Tags: android, google-maps, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm using the nativescript-google-maps-sdk plugin (Nativescript) created by Dapriett, but I can't figure out how to place a button (or anything else besides plain text) inside the InfoWindow.
I really need this for a project of mine, so any advice is very welcome...!

Comment: I reviewed the plugin and was unable to find appropriate way to add another view inside the `Marker`. Could you provide some more info about your scenario and about the need to add `Button` inside the `Marker` Info.

Comment: Currently there is only the posibillity to add plain text to the Marker, by setting the 'snippet' property. Problem is I need more than just plain text, I need to display a button, an image, a link, or whatever inside the Marker Info Window... 

What I actually try to accomplish here, when someone clicks a marker, the InfoWindow should popup. In the InfoWindow I want to display some information such as a title, text with hyperlinks or buttons (like a 'detail' button, or 'goto' button)... Hope you can read my terrible English... ;-)

Comment: You could use the markerSelect event and create an in-app infoWindow about this marker or use the markerInfoWindowTapped  event to create an in-app detail view (those events are the events of the nativescript-google-maps-sdk plugin)

Comment: That sounds like a workaround that could work... Any ideas how to create such an InfoWindow, what component should I use as absulote container?

Answer (score 0):

Currently building a plugin for Nativescript to handle this the "right" way, because no such feature is available yet...